# How do I share a block of code among all websites inside nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx

I'm new to the nginx system, but there is a first for everything. After trying and failing for over three days, I finally found the solution for my 404 error on Wordpress pages after my migration from Apache to nginx. As I'm using HTTPS/SSL, I had to add the line of code below to each site's `/location block`, inside `snginx.conf`, instead of the good 'ol `nginx.conf`

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

Adding that manually for one site isn't a pain, but having to add that for every website added to the server is a burden.

As this is a line required for every Wordpress site on my server, I was wondering **how to write a single block of code and have it applied to every `server { location / {...} }` inside `snginx.conf?**

---

*This, assuming it has no effect on non-wordpress (i.e. non PHP) websites, since my server only consists of regular HTML and Wordpress-PHP websites.*

Answer (score 1):

You should use the nginx [include](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive.

Explanation from the above link:

> Includes another file, or files matching the specified mask, into
>   configuration. Included files should consist of syntactically correct
>   directives and blocks.
>
> Usage example:
>
> `include mime.types; include vhosts/*.conf;`

Comment: But that is the other way around. When adding a new website to the file, I have to include the `include` line. Instead, I want a general block that applies to every `server {}` inside the file by default, no matter what is inside some `server {}` block. - I might be unclear, feel free to say so. To clarify with a little bit of a metaphor; 'include' is like a pull-request, while what I want is an automated 'push' request to each block. "Shut up and take this!", instead of "Mommy, can I have that?"

Comment: I'm fairly certain what you're looking for isn't possible. How would the system know **where** in your server block to apply the configuration? `include` is likely the closest you'll get.

Comment: Based on what I know I agree with EA. You need to explicitly include.

Comment: I've automated creating those server blocks for each website on my server to prevent me from making mistakes. Those blocks are generated by a template and I was looking for something complex, whilst it could be fixed by adding a line to the template. Very stupid of me. However, that include is helpful. Thank you!